# Find a basis for the intersection of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let
$\mathbb{U} = \left\{ \rho\left( x \right)\in \mathbb{R}\left[ x;4 \right]\vert\rho\left( -1 \right)=0\ \text{and}\ \rho\left( 2 \right)=0\right\}
 \ \text{and} \ \mathbb{W} = \left\{ \rho\left( x \right)\in \mathbb{R}\left[ x;4 \right]\vert\rho\left(1\right)=0\right\}$

I have to use Factor theorem, but i do not know how to apply it and find intersection.

$(x + 1)$, $(x - 2)$ and $(x - 1)$ are factors for polynomials

The polynomial of degree $4$ with roots at $-1$, $2$, and $1$ can be written in factored form as follows:

$p(x) = (x + 1)(x - 2)(x - 1)(x - 1)$

The polynomial would take the form:

$p(x) = x^4 - 3x^3 - 2x^2 + 3x + 2$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Digitallis i do not know how to find them, maybe they're -1, 2 and 1?

Comment: Ok, then, (x + 1), (x - 2) and (x - 1) are factors for polynomials. But i do not know what to do next, how to find a basis for these

Answer (score 0):

> The polynomial of degree $4$ with roots at $-1$, $2$, and $1$ can be written in factored form as follows:
> $p(x) = (x + 1)(x - 2)(x - 1)(x - 1)$

That is not correct. There is no reason to think that $1$ is a root of multiplicity $2$.

If $\omega\in\Bbb U\cap\Bbb W$, then  $\omega\in\Bbb U$ and  $\omega\in\Bbb W$. Thus,
$$\omega\in\Bbb R[4;x] \ \text{and} \ \omega(-1)=0 \ \text{and} \ \omega(1)=0 \ \text{and} \ \omega(2)=0.$$
In other words, $\omega$ is a polynomial of degree $4$ with roots $-1,1$, and $2$, which means that $\omega(x)$ can be factored as
\begin{align}\omega(x)&=(x+1)(x-1)(x-2)(ax+b)\\
&=a(x^4-2x^3-x^2+2x)+b(x^3-2x^2-x+2).\end{align}
where $a,b\in\Bbb R.$ Therefore, we can conclude that
$$\Bbb U\cap\Bbb W=\{a(x^4-2x^3-x^2+2x)+b(x^3-2x^2-x+2)\vert a,b\in\Bbb R\}.$$